# Как искать по свойствам товара mFilter2?

Tags: modx, minishop2

У `minishop` есть много полей в свойствах товара. Но `mFilter2` ищет только по заголовку. А что, если мне нужно искать к примеру по артиклю? Есть ли у него такой параметр, в котором можно указать по каким полям искать? В документации к плагину нашёл параметр &`includeTVs`

Там написано:

> &includeTVs - Список ТВ параметров для выборки, через запятую.
>   Например: «action,time» дадут плейсхолдеры [[+action]] и [[+time]].

На странице поиска, вывожу:

```
[[!mSearch2? 
    &parents=`12`
    &includeTVs=`article`
]]
```

Но безрезультатно… я по прежнему вижу текст что результатов нет

Comment: После установки mSearch2-расширения, через админку поисковый индекс обновили?

Comment: @Jigius Да, я уже решил проблему. Оказывается всё через поисковый индекс и делается